# Windows forms event when the form comes back on focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms: Form1 and Form2

Form1 has got a button to launch Form2. 
Form2 appears as a pop up with Form1 still shown in the background. 
When Form2 is closed by pressing X i need some action to occur on Form1 (like refreshing the data it has got because the input made on Form2 might have impacted it).

I have tried events like Activated, Shown, Enter, GotFocus, VisibleChanged on Form1 to see if any of these get triggered when Form1 comes back to life but they did not help.

How can this be achieved this please?
What event is triggered when Form1 comes back to focus after Form2 is closed.

Comment: Need the `Form1` be active when `Form2` is visible/active? When not, you can use modal version - `ShowDialog()` when activating `Form2`.

Comment: When Form2 is visible Form1 is anyway not in focus and just stays in the background. I need an event which would be fired off as soon as Form1 comes back to focus again.

Comment: If you have to ask this question then you almost certainly need to use ShowDialog() to display the 2nd form.  Pay attention to the return value, you have to give your user an opportunity to undo this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();

        f2.Closed += F2_Closed;
    }

    private void F2_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form2 was closed");
    }
```

Comment: @Sri Great! Mark it as answer :)

Comment: The answer is invalid. OP should use `ShowDialog`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Why would that be invalid?

Comment: The solution worked with the problem i was solving. Sorry @Baral indeed it was marked as answer but it does not count as i do not have enough reputation

Answer (score 3):

If Form1 has an instance of Form2 then you can handle the FormClosing event of Form2 in Form1:

```
public Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreateForm2();
    }

    public void CreateForm2()
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.FormClosing += form2_FormClosing;
    }

    public void form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // This bit removes the event handler so clears up memory leaks
        Form2 form2 = sender as Form2;
        if (form2 != null)
        {
            form2.FormClosing -= form2_FormClosing;
        }

        // Do stuff here when form2 is closed
    }
}
```

Comment: Fine solution +1, Minor thing, if you always expect that the sender is a `Form2`, cast it instead of using `as`. If a `Form3` is passed, the event will never be unregistered. When casting is used, you'll get an exception that implies a programming mistake has been made.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using `ShowDialog()`:

In `Form2`:

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            // use whichever DialogResult is applicable - the option to cancel might be nice.
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
```

In `Form1`:

```
Form2 frmPopup = new Form2();
            if (frmPopup.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // do whatever needs to happen when Form2 closes
            }
```